# what is the output of element.classList?

Tags: javascript, contains

Can somebody please tell me what's wrong with the below code?  It won't run.  What is the return of startNode.classList?

```
var startNode = document.body
if (startNode.classList.contains(className) {output.push(startNode)};
```

if I do the below, it runs.

```
if (('' + startNode.classList + '').indexOf(className) > -1) {
  output.push(startNode)
}
```

Comment: your top code is missing a `)` for the if statement, you should be seeing a syntax error on your console log

Comment: learn to use your console to check for script errors ... *give a man a fish, or teach him to fish*

Comment: [`classList`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-classlist) returns a [`DOMTokenList`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#domtokenlist).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code works fine if you don't write syntax errors:

```
if (startNode.classList.contains(className) {output.push(startNode)}; 
    missing a closing parentheses here ---^
```

[More about the API itself here](http://html5doctor.com/the-classlist-api/).

Do keep in mind that `classList` [won't work in IE9-](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist).

Comment: Thanks Niels,  I wasted like 2+ hours wondering why the heck it wouldn't work.  :)